# Python multprocessing tkinter не могу поменять свойства окна используя процессы

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter

Изучаю multiprocessing...

Пытаюсь поменять свойства окна tkinter используя процессы

Не получается

Помогите пожалуйста

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import tkinter as tk



def f(lo, c, la):
    lo.acquire()
    la.config(bg=c)
    lo.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    lock = Lock()
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(text='This is Label', font=('Courier', 30))
    label.pack()
    for color in ['red', 'green', 'blue']:
        p = Process(target=f, args=(lock, color, label))
        p.start()
        #p.join()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А зачем вам использовать процессы? Мб, хватит и потоков?

Comment: хочу изучить процессы ))

Comment: Так как у вас память между основным процессом и тот который вы создаете не общая, то управлять напрямую элементами не получится. Если вы хотите что-то из процесса в gui менять вам нужны средства межпроцессного взаимодействия. Самый простой вариант очередь. Помещаете в очередь из процесса что нужно поменять, а в основном процессе отслеживаете и меняете.

Comment: Могу Вас попросить модифицировать код?